# IBM Watson Visual recognition. Is it possible to get X,Y coordinates from an specific object?

Tags: api, ibm-watson, visual-recognition

I'm starting with an university project and I'm looking for a tool that help me to find the coordinates(X,Y) in pixels from an specific objects in an image(I'm not talking about text). I'm trying to know if IBM Watson Visual recognition could help me out to get this achieve, or if you know any other tool that could work better.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also take a hybrid "cloud-edge" approach, as described here: https://medium.com/unsupervised-coding/dont-miss-your-target-object-detection-with-tensorflow-and-watson-488e24226ef3

It uses a TensorFlow model running locally to detect regions, then uses Watson VR to say what is in each region.  This combines the flexibility of TensorFlow with the ability of Watson VR to classify many many (tens of thousands of) different types of objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can "kind of" do this with Watson visual recognition.  First you need to train a custom classifier to "find" the objects that you are looking for.  Once you have done this, you're halfway done.

The second part involves taking the image that you want to find the object in, and splitting it up into four parts (upper left, lower left, upper right, lower right).  Then you search each portion of the image for your target object.  If you find it in one of those quadrants, you then take that quadrant and break it up into four parts, and search each portion of the image for the target object.  If you continue and do this recursively (and keep track of the pixel boundaries of each quadrant and sub-quadrant), eventually you will narrow down on the object you are searching for.

Now you should also want to do other search algorithms. Consider the case where your target object is in the center of the image - it won't show up in ANY quadrant.  If your object happens to span a quadrant boundary, you will not get an accurate location, so multiple search patterns are needed, but the strategy and approach is the same.